# Find and explain the significance of these one-sided limits.

Tags: limits

A patient receives a 150-mg injection of a drug every 4 hours. The graph shows the amount f(t) of the drug in the bloodstream after t hours. Find

$\begin{align*} & Limf(t)\\ & t\rightarrow 12^+\end{align*}$ and $\begin{align*} & Limf(t)\\ & t\rightarrow 12^-\end{align*}$

and explain the significance of these one-sided limits.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0j9Y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{t \to 12^-} f(t)=150mg$$
$$\lim_{t \to 12^+} f(t)=300mg$$

The first limit says that the amount of drug at the end of the eleventh hour is $150$mg (like at the beginning), because the body has absorbed the drug, but right after, at the beginning of the twelfth hour, the patient receives a new injection so there is a peak for the amount of drug in the bloodstream.

Comment: Woaawww that's amazing. I have never think that..